# Challenge online Xcode

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, online-game

I'm ready for made my second app whit Xcode. 
For the first I used cocos2d, a simple game. Now I want create an app where two players can challenge, like RUZZLE for example.
The player register whit my app and play whit other players.

Can I do that? Do I need a server? Do i need to use api code of the app or apple?
Can I use facebook? Can i use my web site?

So, I don't know how start. Is there a plugin in cocos2d which I can use?
I don't find any tutorial about this.

PS: I don't want to use game center.

Comment: what you need to do is research. There's no simple, ready-made solution and a plethora of choices. At the least you need Game Center.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's what [GameKit](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/Introduction/Introduction.html) and Game Center is for.

Players can login with Game Center, and you can use GameKit for [match making](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/MatchmakingwithGameCenter/MatchmakingwithGameCenter.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008304-CH12-SW2), sending [challenges](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/Challenges/Challenges.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008304-CH18-SW14) to other players and managing [leaderboards](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/LeaderBoards/LeaderBoards.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008304-CH6-SW13) or [achievements](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/Achievements/Achievements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008304-CH7-SW13).